# How to format a date string in ISO 8601 format(2022-04-10T15:58:25.549+01:00) in Javascript under POSTMAN?

Tags: javascript, json, postman

const d = new Date();
console.log(d);            // output is 2022-04-11T10:29:46.644Z

The above code showing time for GMT, but i want to print time for Ex: GMT+1 in format like "2022-04-11T10:29:46.644+01:00.

I am using postman so can not use moment-timezone
My current code:

var date = new Date().toISOString(true);
pm.environment.set("todaydate", date);

"errorSource": "Invalid date offset for value 2022-10-11T13:24:37.197z of offset is +01:00.

i.e  value should be 2022-10-11T13:24:37+01:00

Comment: `Moment` can be used in Postman, it's one of the included modules. Just use `require('moment')` to access it in the script sandbox.

Comment: [toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) supposed to output ISO 8601

Comment: `Date` doesn't keep track of a time zone, internally it's just a number. So, where do you want the `+01:00` or `+05:30` parts come from?

Comment: I have to pass date and time in format 2022-04-10T13:37:50+01:00 as input but toISOString() giving output as 202-04-10T13:37:50z

Comment: `2022-04-10T13:37:50Z` is ISO 8601 format and the expected output of `toISOString`: _"The timezone is always zero UTC offset, as denoted by the suffix "`Z`"."_

Comment: `2022-04-11T10:29:46.644Z`, `2022-04-11T10:29:46.644+01:00` and `2022-04-11T10:29:46.644+05:30` are different timestamps. Is this expected?

Comment: but i want to print current london timezone which is now GMT +1 in format 2022-04-13T10:29:45.644+01:00

Answer (score 0):

you can timezone info from  `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()`

```js
const timeoffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
console.log(timeoffset) 
//output : -330 which is  GMT -330minutes 

//you can convert to hours using
const inHours = timeoffset>0 ?
'-'+Math.floor(timeoffset/60).toString().padStart(2,'0')+':'+(timeoffset%60).toString().padEnd(2,'0')
:
Math.floor((-1*timeoffset)/60).toString().padStart(2,'0')+':'+((-1*timeoffset)%60).toString().padEnd(2,'0')
console.log(inHours);
```

Answer (score 0):

If moment.js is not an option, can you can use dayjs - https://day.js.org/